# Can "PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF" SQLite statement be used inside a TypeORM migration?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM (v0.2.18) with Node.js (v12.7.0) to perform migrations in my SQLite database.

This is my situation: I have a table named `country` and a table named `workflow`. I want to remove one of the columns, named `name`, of `country` but `workflow` references `country` through this column.

Playing with DB Browser for SQLite I could remove the column successfully with these statements:

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE country_backup(id, createdAt, updatedAt, enabled, codeIso2);
INSERT INTO country_backup SELECT id, createdAt, updatedAt, enabled, codeIso2 FROM country;
DROP TABLE country;
CREATE TABLE country(id, createdAt, updatedAt, enabled, codeIso2);
INSERT INTO country SELECT id, createdAt, updatedAt, enabled, codeIso2 FROM country_backup;
DROP TABLE country_backup;
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
```

Which I used in a TypeORM migration like this:

```js
...
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.query("PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF");
    await queryRunner.query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE country_backup(id, createdAt, updatedAt, enabled, codeIso2)");
    await queryRunner.query("INSERT INTO country_backup SELECT id, createdAt, updatedAt, enabled, codeIso2 FROM country");
    await queryRunner.query("DROP TABLE country");
    await queryRunner.query("CREATE TABLE country(id, createdAt, updatedAt, enabled, codeIso2)");
    await queryRunner.query("INSERT INTO country SELECT id, createdAt, updatedAt, enabled, codeIso2 FROM country_backup");
    await queryRunner.query("DROP TABLE country_backup");
    await queryRunner.query("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
}
...
```

But I get this error:

```
Error during migration run:
QueryFailedError: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
    at new QueryFailedError (/.../api/src/error/QueryFailedError.ts:9:9)
    at Statement.handler (/.../src/driver/sqlite/SqliteQueryRunner.ts:53:26)
    at Statement.replacement (/.../api/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:19:31)
    at Statement.replacement (/.../api/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:19:31) {
  message: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed',
  errno: 19,
  code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT',
  name: 'QueryFailedError',
  query: 'DROP TABLE country',
  parameters: []
}
```

Why did it work in DB Browser for SQLite but not with TypeORM? It's like it ignored the PRAGMA statement.

Based on [this](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html), I tried with both `PRAGMA foreign_keys` and `PRAGMA legacy_alter_table` (setting them OFF and ON (before any action) and ON and OFF (after any action), respectively).

I tried using the PRAGMA's both inside the `up()` function and outside it. Outside it means I put the statements before and after `await typeOrmConnection.runMigrations()` in my `main.ts` file, like `await typeOrmConnection.query("PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF")`.

Answer (score 5):

The sqlite docs say that you can't set `PRAGMA foreign_keys=off` while executing multiple statements, so I tried this and got it work by separating the PRAGMA statements from the others.

A transaction has been started already for the query runner instance passed to the `up()` function. Therefore, end the existing transaction immediately, then use an outside-of-transaction query to turn off the checks, and then start another transaction.

Write the rest of your non-PRAGMA code within the new transaction.

Right before the end of the function, commit the inner transaction, then use a regular single-statement query to turn the key checks back on, and then start another transaction (so that there will be something to automatically close after `up()` runs, otherwise you get an error).

```
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
    await queryRunner.query('PRAGMA foreign_keys=off');
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();

    // the rest of your queries

    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
    await queryRunner.query('PRAGMA foreign_keys=on');
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();
}
```

Comment: There is a recommended method to do this in this issue response thread: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9206#issuecomment-1192383639